# How to replace Pubcenter controls with same sized AdDuplex controls using XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, ads

I have a Windows 8 Store app and use the Pubcenter for advertising. I want to use the AdDuplex control when Pubcenter could not deliver an ad.

I use this XAML code:

```
<StackPanel Height="600" Width="160" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="2">
    <adDuplex:AdControl x:Name="AdDuplexAdControl" AppId="MyAdDuplexID" Width="160" Height="600" Visibility="Collapsed" />
    <UI:AdControl x:Name="MSAdMainView" ApplicationId="MyPubCenterID" AdUnitId="MyAdControlID" Height="600" Width="160" ErrorOccurred="MSAdMainView_ErrorOccurred" Visibility="Visible"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And replace the Pubcenter control with this C# code:

```
//hide PubCenter and display AdDuplex
private void MSAdMainView_ErrorOccurred(object sender, Microsoft.Advertising.WinRT.UI.AdErrorEventArgs e)
{
    MSAdMainView.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
    AdDuplexAdControl.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;           
}
```

but somehow the AdDuplex control resizes back to the standard 300x300 ad size and isn´t showing at size of 160x600. My App isn´t certified yet. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Size property on the AdDuplex control to set the size of the ad. Size="160x600" in your case.

Comment: Thanks, that worked for the 160x600 control...and whats the size for the pubcenter 90x728 control? Your client area is currently down...otherwise i would have looked it up :-) `<adDuplex:AdControl x:Name="AdDuplexAdControl" AppId="MyAdDuplexID" Size="90x728" Visibility="Collapsed" />` isnt working

Comment: 728x90 (WxH). All the sizes are listed in the docs here https://adduplex.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200118482-Windows-8-1-XAML-AdControl-Installation-and-Usage-C-VB-NET-C-